# Migrate from UIWebview to WKWebview

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

I need to migrating from UIWebView to WKWebView but i cant. Does anyone know?

```
importUIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let URL:String = "https://google.com"

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = NSURL (string: URL);
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL);
    webView.loadRequest(requestObj as URLRequest);
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: what problem do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to change, the `UIWebView` for `WKWebView` add `import WebKit` and change the class name for your Outlet to WKWebView, also change the `loadRequest` for `load`

```
import UIKit
import WebKit



class ViewController: UIViewController {

 @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

      let urlString: String = "https://google.com"

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         guard let url =  URL(string: urlString) else { return }
         let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url)
         webView.load(requestObj)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: "NS" is not required now a days!

Comment: @AshishKakkad is not required but the compilator don't complain about it ;), anyway thanks and is fixed

Answer (score 0):

The new API will be the same

`wkWebView.load(URLRequest(url: url))`